# Sitefnity Mailing List Export Generates Wrong URL

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

Configuration of web servers:

My Sitfinity CMS website is deployed on three servers in which two are on load balancer and serve only frontend website, 3rd server in only serve CMS backend and only accessible within organization domain and not part of the loadbalancer.

Backend URL is cms.example.com 
Frontend URL is web.example.com

When I go to Marketing --> Mailing lists then click on Action --> Export, select file format and click on "Export", it does not export any file.
When I look at browser console it shows me wrong (web URL) URL for export file.

http:///web.example.com/Telerik.Sitefinity.ExportSubscribersHttpHandler.ashx?provName=&isCSV=true&ids=c46d5106-e7fa-490b-93f5-0c7106ad8a61&exportExSub=true&allSub=false

In order to download file, I need to generate the below URL
http:///cms.example.com/Telerik.Sitefinity.ExportSubscribersHttpHandler.ashx?provName=&isCSV=true&ids=c46d5106-e7fa-490b-93f5-0c7106ad8a61&exportExSub=true&allSub=false

How can I fix this issue for Mailing List Export file?

Comment: if both servers are pointing to the same db, why would they have different URLs? Maybe touch the local hosts file and make it so that web.example.com points to the CMS server and always use web.example.com to access the site

Comment: It is our client requirement. CMS Server is intranet based also it does not have access to Web servers and is used for only editing and managing content. Web Servers are not connected to CMS Server as well.

Comment: Please see updated **question**